# Socket Program in C, a send message blocking further code

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

I am new to socket programming and i currently facing a problem send/receiving information between my client and server. Currently i am sending "TRN" to my client which is received and handled on my client side but then my program gets stuck. The console prints the `[DEBUG] Sent start message.` but then it never makes it to the `MADE IT HERE 1` message.  On the client side when it receives the "TRN" it is handled and an int is sent back to the server which i want to be received however it doesn't make it that far. This is my code breakdown:

```
/* Send the start message. */
write_client_msg(cli_sockfd, "TRN");
printf("\n[DEBUG] Sent start message.\n");
int place_reveal = 0;
printf("\nMADE IT HERE 1");
place_reveal = recv_int(cli_sockfd);
printf("\nThis is the users results: %d", place_reveal);

/* Writes a message to a client socket. */
void write_client_msg(int cli_sockfd, char * msg)
{
    int n = write(cli_sockfd, msg, strlen(msg));
    if (n < 0)
        error("ERROR writing msg to client socket");

}

/* Reads an int from a client socket. */
int recv_int(int cli_sockfd)
{
    printf(" MADE IT HERE 2");

    int msg = 0;
    int n = read(cli_sockfd, &msg, sizeof(int));

    if (n < 0 || n != sizeof(int)) /* Not what we were expecting. Client likely disconnected. */
        return -1;

    printf("[DEBUG] Received int: %d\n", msg);

    return msg;
}
```

What i have found although is that when i hit Control C to exit the program the console output is this:

```
^C
MADE IT HERE 1 MADE IT HERE 2
OUCH you hit Ctrl-C?!
Goodbye!
```

Comment: So, it's stuck on the read().  Is this TCP?  Whatever way, you should wireshark the line to be sure that the client reply is actually sent to the server.

Comment: Put a \n at the end of each message you print.

Comment: Note that any `printf()` text that isn't followed by a carriage return (`\n`) will be held in stdout's output buffer and will not appear in your terminal window until either a carriage return is printed, or your program explicitly calls `fflush(stdout);` to flush the buffer.  Several of your `printf()` calls do not end with a `\n`, and that may be the source of some confusion about where your program is actually blocking at.